# How to set Table of Contents page numbers ragged right?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir

First post and certainly a tyro at LaTeX. Thanks to all those who have made this site such a helpful resource.

I'm using the `memoir` class to typeset a novel, and would like to have the Table of Contents *page numbers* appear *ragged right*, each page number set a fixed horizontal distance from the end of each chapter title, regardless of chapter title length. I would like to be able to try different spacings to find the most pleasing horizontal gap between the end of chapter title lines and the page numbers.

Any solutions or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the family of commands `\cftXleader` `\cftXafterpnum` as shown below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To control the distance you could define auxiliary lengths to be used as the box width used by `\cftXformatpnum` to format the page number:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength\chaplength
\newlength\seclength
\setlength\chaplength{7em}
\setlength\seclength{2em}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{%
  \hbox to \chaplength{\hfill{\cftchapterpagefont #1}}}

\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{%
  \hbox to \seclength{\hfill{\cftsectionpagefont #1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]