# Changing the appearance of list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I want to change the appearance of the list of figures to roughly what I have under "New List of Figures" in the example below: Between the header for the lof and the entries I want a line with two subheadings in small caps, "figure" and "caption". Then, after some vertical space, the figure number, horizontal space, the caption, then no dotted line but only a small space, and then the page number. I understand that latex doesn't handle lof, toc etc. as tables but as lists, I formatted it as a table only for the example.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{float}
% \usepackage{tocloft} % Actually I haven't used it yet.
\usepackage{ltablex}

\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\afterloftitle{}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures


\section*{New List of Figures}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX}
\textsc{figure} & \textsc{caption}\\
\\
0.1 & myfigureA \quad 1\\
0.2 & myfigureB \quad 1\\
0.3 & myfigureC has a longer caption, longer than a line. Still a little bit longer. \quad 1\\
\end{tabularx}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
AAA\\
AAA\\
AAA\\
\caption{myfigureA}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
BBB\\
BBB\\
BBB\\
\caption{myfigureB}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
CCC\\
CCC\\
CCC\\
\caption{myfigureC has a longer caption, longer than a line. Still a little bit longer.} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

EDIT: [Mike Renfro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254848/59023) almost works for me, but there's one problem with the long caption, namely its last word and the number get printed at the end of the line:

[image: changed example]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}

\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\afterloftitle{\vspace{\baselineskip}\textsc{Figure\quad Caption}\\}

\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{\widthof{\textsc{Figure\quad}}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureA}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureB}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureC has a longer caption, longer than a line. Still a little bit longer.} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Memoir includes most of all of tocloft's functionality. Start reading chapter 9 of the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (Contents Lists), especially section 9.2 (The Class ToC Methods) while I see if there's a simple answer.

Comment: Adding `\textsc` or `\quad` appears to be the root cause of your current problem. Don't have a good fix for it yet.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I am now experimenting with your answer in my "real file", with quite a few entries, with simple `\renewcommand\afterloftitle{Figure Caption}` and `\renewcommand\afterloftitle{Figure Caption}`, no `\quad`, `\textsc`, `\vspace{\baselineskip}` or `\\`. The problem remains, so as far as I can see it doesn't lie in any of these.

Comment: @MikeRenfro As far as I can see your answer works when an entry in the lof is only one line, or the last line of the caption contains only one word. Try adding a few more words to figure 3 and you'll see.

Comment: Ragged right entries ensure now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer doesn't include the `float` or `ltablex` packages, since they don't appear to affect things one way or the other. If you want a small caps heading above the LoF, just adjust the `\afterloftitle` and `\widthof` commands accordingly.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating width of LoF headings

\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\afterloftitle{Figure Caption}
% adds a line of text after the LoF title
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{\widthof{Figure }}
% instead of "Figure " including the space, you can use whatever precedes the
% "Caption" header above
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
% removes the dot leader between the figure title and the page number
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
% Ensure ragged right overall (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53057/)

\begin{document}
{\raggedright
\listoffigures
}
\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureA}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureB}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureC has a longer caption, longer than a line. Maybe a good bit longer. Or even longer still.} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there, but one problem remains, see my edit above.

Comment: If in your example I want to change the Heading to be formatted like a chapter heading via `\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\chapter*{#1}}` I get two blank pages inserted at the beginning of the file. Any idea why that is so and how I can turn it off? Or, assuming that I could just comment out that line because per default the LoF title is printed like a chapter title, "Figure Caption" surprisingly appears in the same line, so that that's also not so easily possible.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256636/two-empty-pages-before-lof