# Two empty pages before LoF

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In the following example I get two empty pages inserted before the LoF, why is that so and how can I get rid of them again? Originally I had the LoF title formatted as a `\section*`, the two empty pages appeared once I changed it to `\chapter*`.  I'm somewhat surprised I need to redefine `\printloftitle` at all, as printing the LoF title like a chapter title is the default, but if I omit it I get `\afterloftitle` printed immediately after the title instead of below it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating width of LoF headings

\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\chapter*{#1}}
\renewcommand\afterloftitle{Figure Caption}
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{\widthof{Figure }}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{myfigureA}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and why are you using `\chapter*` in the first place?

Comment: @daleif See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254834/changing-the-appearance-of-list-of-figures .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason at all to use `\chapter*` here, as it is basically what it is already doing. But before you mess with `\afterloftitle` it might be an idea to take a look at what that macro is actually doing.

This works

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating width of LoF headings

\renewcommand\afterloftitle{\afterchaptertitle
  \normalsize\normalfont Figure Caption
  \par\smallskip
}
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{\widthof{Figure }}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{myfigureA}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```